# What does this paragraph from the book Capital Markets mean?

Tags: market

Gary Strumeyer writes in "The Capital Markets: Evolution of the Financial Ecosystem"

> Chronic wariness rules the capital market mindset in the Teens. And little wonder. “Manipulated” market valuations (especially suppressed bond yields) rest on pillars of unprecedented economic stimulus largesse, especially from central banks. Policymakers are assailed for doing too little or too much. In many investment arenas, the search for portfolio alpha generation has morphed into sideline‐standing, index‐hugging capital preservation. Returns from alternative investment strategies, particularly by macro hedge funds, have proven less bountiful and consistent.

- What does this paragraph mean in general?
- What does in the "Teens" mean? The 2012-2019 period?
- What are manipulated market valuations? How do bond yields get suppressed?
- What is sideline‐standing, index‐hugging capital preservation?
- What are macro hedge funds? I understand that hedge funds are a pooled monetary resource that aims to increase the value of the money held, but what is a macro and micro hedge fund?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not being the author and missing context I can only try to give an answer:

- In the period 2010-2019 investors are always on the lookout for when the market will crash.
- The period 2010-2019, we are in the twenties now: 2020-2029.
- Central banks have been using all kinds of tools to suppress yields and prop up asset prices. They did this by providing banks with cheap funding and by buying bonds.
- People passively following an index (through for example ETF's or mutual funds) whatever happens.
- A macro hedge fund is a fund that tries to profit by identifying macro economics trends. There is no such thing as a micro hedge fund but there are a number of other [hedge fund styles](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/111313/multiple-strategies-hedge-funds.asp).